# htaccess redirection of url with param like p=2

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need to redirect

http://www.example.com/es/?p=2%3Fp%3D2

to

http://www.example.com/es/

I tried with 301, and with rewriterule, but without luck
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /es/\?p=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /es/? [L,R=301]
```

The empty question mark **?** at the end of the rule's target is important as it discards the old querystring. Don't remove this otherwise  you will get a redirect loop error.